# Speeding up Google Cloud Dataflow Pub/Sub read frequency

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Java Dataflow job that reads from PubSub.  It takes roughly 5 seconds for a message to be read by Dataflow.

How can I speed this up?  I'm assuming Dataflow is pulling from PubSub instead of PubSub pushing the message to Dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reading from PubSub using a subscription rather than a topic. Like below

`PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
         .fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()))`

For pull/push, during subscription creation google pubsub provides two delivery options.

1. PULL - Subscriber requests delivery (default option)
2. PUSH - Messages are delivered as soon as they are published

May be, if you share code which you are using to achieve read that might be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Yea, my beam code is similar:
    PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(options.getInputPubsubSubscription())

When I try to create a PUSH subscription in the Google Pubsub web UI, it asks for a Endpoint URL.  I don't know what to put when running on Dataflow.  I assume there is a common solution to this and didn't want to reinvent a solution.